# Make Jade (Pug) fail if variable cannot be resolved

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

It seems that if Jade (Pug) cannot resolve a variable it treats it as not set.

Is there a possibility to make it fail during rendering of the template?

Controller code:

```
exports.index = function (req, res) {
    res.render('index', {})
};
```

Template code:

extends layout

```
block content
    p Value is "#{val}"
```

Result:

```
<p>Value is ""</p>
```

This does not detect bugs early and thus I would like Jade to throw an exception when something like this happens. Is it possible ?

Comment: show the code please.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [conditionals](http://jade-lang.com/reference/conditionals/) for this like so:

```
block content
  if val
    p Value is "#{val}"
  else
    p Value is undefined
```

or

```
block content
  if val !== ""
    p Value is "#{val}"
  else
    p Value is undefined
```